# List control breaks after grouping aggregation

Tags: sapui5

I have two problems with a `sap.m.List`. I'm trying to group values by a given date.

1. The grouping shows duplicates group headers, despite having the same values.
2. The actual list items are not showing at all.

I'm binding everything in the controller. When I remove the sorter, the list behaves correctly and shows all data correctly. But **as soon as I add the grouping, the list breaks**.

[image: Screenshot]

XML View (the item is more complex, for simplicity all other variables have been removed):

```xml
<List id="idListCart" noDataText="{i18n>CartListNoData}">
  <CustomListItem id="listItemTemplate">
    <layout:Grid class="sapUiSmallMarginTop" hSpacing="1">
      <VBox alignItems="Start" class="sapUiSmallMarginEnd">
        <Text text="{Fullname}" />
        <Text text="{Startdatum}" />
      </VBox>
    </layout:Grid>
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

Controller:

```js
this.byId("idListCart").bindItems({
  path: "/CartSet",
  template: this.byId("listItemTemplate"),
  filters: aFilters,
  sorter: new Sorter({ // required from "sap/ui/model/Sorter"
    path: "Startdatum",
    group: function(oContext) {
      return /* formatted date */;
    }
  }),
  groupHeaderFactory: function(oGroup) {
    return new GroupHeaderListItem({ // required from "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem"
      title: oGroup.key
    });
  },
});
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it's not a good practice to declare a template in XML without predefining the corresponding list binding in the parent control. Otherwise, it's just adding a plain single item which UI5 renders together with the List initially. That single item gets then cloned and replaced in the 2nd rendering cycle after the list binding from the controller is complete. I guess this is where the grouping has issues; the first item is no longer `sap.m.CustomListItem` but `sap.m.GroupHeaderListItem` causing side effects when rendering the rest of the items.

Better create the template in the controller entirely:

```xml
<List id="idListCart" noDataText="{i18n>CartListNoData}">
  <!-- Template control is created in the controller. Nothing to define here. -->
</List>
```

```js
{ // Items binding info
  path: "/CartSet",
  templateShareable: false,
  template: new CustomListItem({ // required from "sap/m/CustomListItem"
    // ...
  }),
  // ...
}
```

This does add quite a few more LOC to the controller but avoids unexpected side effects.

We *could* keep the template definition in XML by wrapping it with `<dependents>` but that practice caused other issues in my experience with some outdated SAPUI5 controls. But you might want to give it a try:

```xml
<List id="idListCart" noDataText="{i18n>CartListNoData}">
  <dependents> <!-- Controls that belong to parent but aren't supposed to be rendered -->
    <CustomListItem id="listItemTemplate">
      <!-- ... -->
    </CustomListItem>
  </dependents>
</List><!-- No change in the controller -->
```

### *Alternative*

If possible, define the list binding directly in XML where `Sorter` can be created declaratively, with its grouper and group header factory assigned using the `'.<fnName>'` syntax. Dynamic filters would still need to be created and added to the list binding separately in the controller.

```xml
<List id="idListCart"
  noDataText="{i18n>CartListNoData}"
  items="{
    path: '/CartSet',
    sorter: {
      path: 'Startdatum',
      descending: true,
      group: '.formatDate'
    },
    groupHeaderFactory: '.createGroupHeader',
    suspended: true
  }"
><!-- Template as usual: -->
  <CustomListItem>
    <!-- ... -->
  </CustomListItem>
</List>
```

The list binding is `suspended` first in order to prevent sending a request prematurely without the $filter query. Once the binding resumes, a single request will be sent instead of two.

```js
{ // Controller

  onInit: async function() {
    const myFilters = new Filter({/* ... */}); // required from "sap/ui/model/Filter"
    await this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().metadataLoaded(); // preventing race condition
    this.byId("idListCart").getBinding("items") // access ODataListBinding
      .filter(myFilters, "Application")
      .resume(); // starts sending the request from here.
  },

  formatDate: function(oContext) {
    return /* formatted date */;
  },

  createGroupHeader: function(oGroup) {
    return new GroupHeaderListItem({ // required from "sap/m/GroupHeaderListItem"
      title: /* formatted group header using oGroup.key */
    });
  },

  // No list binding from controller
}
```

Comment: 1. Thank you for your awesome answer! Adding the <dependents> worked great for solving the second issue. However, it still shows duplicates grouping headers: https://imgur.com/a/Gocst4O
Any ideas? 


2. You mentioned: "Dynamic filters would still need to be created and added to the list binding separately in the controller." What is the best code practice to add dynamic filters in the controller, but still bind the list in xml?

Comment: @jor For the second issue about the duplicated header, we need more information. Since I could not reproduce it, I assume it's dependent on the model data and how they're formatted before feeding them to the grouper. That information is missing in this question. I'd suggest to open a new question with more details or preferably an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). About adding filters in the controller; I enhanced my answer above to give an example.

Comment: @jor There was a mistake in the last code snippet (Controller). The ODataListBinding should be accessed after metadataLoaded since the view is not attached to its parent initially. Fixed it now.